# Weird bias when assigning value in simple loop

Tags: ios, swift

```
class func generatePuzzle(manager: MDLTileManager, withGivens givens:Array<Int>, atPositions positions:Array<TileIndexPath>){
    NSLog("\(givens.count), \(positions.count)");
    //Doesn't work
    for index in 0...positions.count-1{
        //Original code before anomaly:
        //var tileindex = positions[index].toIndex();
        //manager.tiles[tileindex].isGiven == true;

        //New code added to test anomaly:
        manager.tiles[index].currentValue == 8;
    }
    //Works
    for index in 0...positions.count-1{
        manager.tiles[index].currentValue = 8
    }

    for index in 0...manager.tiles.count-1{
        manager.tiles[index].currentValue = 8;
        manager.tiles[index].isGiven = true;
    }
}
```

The first for loop in this snippet was working fine yesterday. Today it's not updating the model like it's suppose to. I couldn't figure out the issue so I've just been trying to brute force it through the use of logs and code snippets.

As  you can see all for loops are identical, but the first for loop does not update the model as the other two do. Any idea how this can be?

`MDLTileManager` is just a wrapper class around an Array that contains my data for my Sudoku Tiles.
This is the relevant code for the tile model

```
struct TileModel {
    var ID = 0;
    var currentValue = 0;
    var solutionValue = 0;
    var possibleValues = Array<Int>();
    var isGiven = false;
    var isHighlighted = false;
    func isCorrect() -> Bool{
        return (solutionValue != 0) && (currentValue == solutionValue);
    }

    init(ID: Int, currentValue current: Int, solutionValue solution: Int, isGiven given:Bool, isHighlighted highlighted:Bool){
        self.ID = ID;
        self.currentValue = current;
        self.solutionValue = solution;
        self.isGiven = given;
        self.isHighlighted = highlighted;
    }   
}
```

Comment: is the `==` in the first loop intended? it is a test for equality and not an assignment

Comment: ... No it isn't. Oh boy... thank you. I have no idea how that got there, but that would be the issue. I've been staring at this for the past hour. I guess sometimes you just need a new set of eyes to see the obvious.